# what is the difference between swapping int pointer and int array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, swap

For educational purposes, I was trying to swap two integer arrays with their memory locations using array pointers but I came across some weird problem and I can't figure out why this is happening,

so when I tried to create an int array and swapped their locations using *swap* function below, only half of their elements changed but when I switched `int fArr[size];` to `int *fArr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);` it works perfectly fine.
Why this is happening and can casting from `&int[]` to `int **` cause a problem?

```
int main(void) {
    ...

    int fArr[size];
    int sArr[size];
    initArr(fArr, sArr, size);
    
    ...

    swapArr((int **)&fArr, (int **)&sArr, size);
}

void initArr(int fArr[], int sArr[], size_t size) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        fArr[i] = rand() % 1000;
        sArr[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }
}

void swapArr(int **fArr, int **sArr, size_t size) {
    int *temp = *fArr;
    *fArr = *sArr;
    *sArr = temp;
}
```

and output of this complete code is

```
Array : 0x7ffcdb611cf0
521, 210, 426, 263

Array : 0x7ffcdb611ce0
553, 314, 17, 16

------- After Swap -------

Array : 0x7ffcdb611cf0
553, 314, 426, 263

Array : 0x7ffcdb611ce0
521, 210, 17, 16
```

Comment: You need to call swapArr with `&fArr`, `&sArr` if you want to manipulate them.

Comment: *and output of this complete code is*... it is difficult to guess what the complete code is doing without you actually posting it :)

Comment: @ypnos I made a typo while I was copying it , sorry.

Comment: @chqrlie, I am just initializing arrays with random values and performing some comparisons but none of them are related to this output, I was just trying to show the elements in the array before and after this swap function

Comment: @yusfux:  *but none of them are related to this output*: The problem with this phrase is you don't really know if the code you don't post is or is not related to the problem you observe. In this case it is not, but it is very common for bugs to hide in innocent looking code that seems unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `swapArr` swaps the values of 2 pointers. You pass the addresses of `int` arrays, inappropriately cast as pointers to `int *`. The code has undefined behavior. What is happening is the first 2 entries of the arrays are swapped because `int *` on your architecture happens to have the size of 2 `int`: for example `int *` on a 64-bit CPU has 8 bytes while `int` is a 32-bit type occupying 4 bytes.

Note that the arguments to `initArrays` are really `int *` despite the declaration syntax `void initArr(int fArr[], int sArr[], size_t size)`. When you pass an array as a function argument (and most other expression contexts) it *decays* as a pointer to its first element.

To swap the array contents, you need to use a loop:

```
void swapArr(int *fArr, int *sArr, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int temp = fArr[i];
        fArr[i] = sArr[i];
        sArr[i] = temp;
    }
}
```